# Move to root view from any where in the application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I need to move user to navigation controller root view whenever user receive push notification.

in my app there is side menu. navigation controllers detail view also.

So if user has opened side menu view then how can I move user to root view of navigationController that is home screen of my application.

also from detail view to root view irrespective of any controller.

Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: If side menu is open then first close it and popToRootViewController, Otherwise you can directly use popToRootViewController.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewController:YES];
```

Or

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```